# draw 2 pixels on canvas scaled to 20 pixels with no blur or texture bleeding

Tags: javascript, html

I draw two pixels from a spritesheet scaled up to 20 pixels on canvas. But the pixels get smoothed and looks blurred. I want crisp pixel perfect scaling with no blur.

This is my code:

```
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

canvas.width = 320;
canvas.height = 180;

canvas.style.width = '1024px';
canvas.style.height = '1024px';

ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

ctx.drawImage(241, 16, 2, 2, 8, 0, 20, 20);

// stylesheet
canvas {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}
```

I've seen this question but that didn't help me [How Can I Prevent Texture Bleeding When Using drawImage To Draw Multiple Images From A Tile Sheet, Sprite Sheet, Or Texture Atlas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60684359/how-can-i-prevent-texture-bleeding-when-using-drawimage-to-draw-multiple-images).

Here's my spritesheet and the resulting image:

[image: bleeding]

[image: bleeding]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to set `imageSmoothingEnabled` to false after resizing the canvas.